# ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement busio (from versions: none)

Tags: python, pip

When Running Installation,

```
pip install busio
```

Getting ERROR,

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement busio (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for busio
```

Python version is 3.7.3.

Comment: what is busio, did you mean buzio `pip install buzio`
is you??

Comment: This question would be more valuable with additional context. _What_ prompted you to install this module? What do you know about this module? There’s almost certainly more background here that would help focus the responses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a module called ["busio"](https://docs.circuitpython.org/en/latest/shared-bindings/busio/) ([GitHub](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Blinka)) by Adafruit which they describe as providing “hardware-driven interfaces for I2C, SPI, UART”.

This can be installed via Adafruit’s Blinka package:

```
pip3 install adafruit-blinka
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no package called `busio`, Maybe you want to install [buzio](https://pypi.org/project/buzio/) which is a python library tool for printing formatted text in terminal, to do so run :

```py
pip install buzio
```

**Testing your installation**

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from buzio import console
today = datetime.now()
yesterday = today - timedelta(days=1)
my_dict = {
"start day": yesterday,
"end day": today
}
console.box(my_dict, date_format="%a, %b-%d-%Y")
```

**OUTPUT :**

```sh
*********************************
*                               *
*  start day: Wed, Nov-03-2021  *
*   end day: Thu, Nov-04-2021   *
*                               *
*********************************
```

Answer (score 0):

You should upgrade your **pip** using `python -m pip install --upgrade pip` or `pip install --upgrade pip` 
 [See more...](https://github.com/apple/turicreate/issues/81)